# Cant access object's method from another package

Tags: java, object, methods

I create my object from a class which is in another package. I cant reach the methods inside it. It is happening just for specific package which is my utilities package.

[image: My Packages]

```
public class Utils {
    public static void usefulMethod(){
        System.out.println("useful method");
    }
}
```

When I create object it shows only Object class methods
[image: When I create object it shows only Object class methods]

For example if I create object from pages classes it shows the methods inside them. It is only happens for utilities package.

Comment: function in Util class is static, try like this

`Util.usefulMethod()`

Comment: Thank you, its been a long time no interact with Java